# Is it possible to remove a 'bot' from the 'bot-list' in Recaptcha v3?

Tags: forms, recaptcha, contacts, recaptcha-v3

I've made a website with a contact form. The contact form works with Recaptcha version 3 (v3). Everything is working, but is it possible to remove an ip-address from the list that is marked as a bot?

When I was testing my website, I always had a score of 0.7, but after testing (too) many times I always had a score of 0.1. I wasn't able to submit the form.

I solved this by creating a new website (with new keys) in the admin console of Recaptcha, but this isn't a good solution.

When the website is live and the customer does something wrong and ends as a bot, I can't generate new keys everytime and publish the 'new' website with this keys.

How can I delete/remove someone's ip address from the 'bot-list', so the score will not be 0.1 anymore?

I already checked the admin console dashboard, but I can't find anything.